# Findstr "<path>" returns wrong result. If using any different string, it works perfectly

Tags: string, windows, batch-file

I'm extracting some specific lines from a XML file in order to generate some .TXT file.
The real XML is much more complex, so this is a very simplified version, just to help to show the problem with the string `<path>` on `FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%X in ('findstr "<path> <descr>" "%input_xml%"')`.

This is the XML (`xmlfile_fruits.xml`):

```
  <fruit>
      <path>./111/222/banana.zip</path>
      <descr>xxx / yyy / zzz</descr>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
      <path>./111/222/orange.zip</path>
      <descr>N/A</descr>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
      <path>./111/222/apple.zip</path>
      <descr></descr>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
      <path>./111/222/lemon.zip</path>
      <descr>xxx / yyy / zzz</descr>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
      <path>./111/222/pineaple.zip</path>
      <descr>abc/def/ghi</descr>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
      <path>./111/222/banana.zip</path>
      <descr></descr>
  </fruit>
```

And this is the Batch I'm using to get 3 lists, one with content from `<path>` and `<descr>`, another with content from `<descr>` only and a third list with the `<descr>` with unique values.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "input_xml=xmlfile_fruits.xml"

if exist List_path.txt del List_path.txt
if exist List_descr.txt del List_descr.txt

FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%X in ('findstr "<path> <descr>" "%input_xml%"') do (
  set "line=%%X"
  if "!line:~0,6%!"=="<path>" (
  set "path=!line:~6,-7!"
  ::get a list with filename.extension only
  for %%I in ("!path!") do echo %%~nI%%~xI>>List.txt
  ) else (
  set "descr=!line:~7,-8!"
  ::get the lists
  echo !descr!>>List.txt
  echo !descr!>>List_descr.txt
  )
)
::remove duplicate lines
if exist "List_unique_descr.txt" del "List_unique_descr.txt"
::scan all the <descr> from List_descr.txt
FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq delims=" %%8 in ("List_descr.txt") do (
  findstr /x /c:"%%~8" "List_unique_descr.txt">NUL || echo %%8>>List_unique_descr.txt
) >nul 2>nul
pause
```

Something wrong is happening on `'findstr "<path> <descr>" "%input_xml%"'`, specifically with the string `<path>`. For some reason the last part of my code is not working, and `"List_unique_descr.txt"` isn't being generated properly.

This is what I get:

```
xxx / yyy / zzz
N/A
ECHO is off.
xxx / yyy / zzz
abc/def/ghi
ECHO is off.
```

Should be this:

```
xxx / yyy / zzz
N/A
ECHO is off.
abc/def/ghi
```

However, if we replace the word `<path>` in `Findstr` for any different one, like `<name>` for example, the code works fine. Of course, it's necessary to replace `<path>` on the XML file as well. But this is not the solution, because I need to respect the XML structure like it is.

And, if I leave `<path>` there, I notice some more errors if I use a Sort command and a Find command as well.

Anyone can help me to understand what is happening?

Comment: Use `PowerShell` instead, _it's part of the OS and has extensive built-in support for `XML`_.

Comment: I think we mentioned in some of your previous questions that what you are doing is brute forcing an xml file.  All three of the other scripting languages that are native to Windows have native methods to read and write XML files.  As the XML gets more complex, using the brute force method will get more difficult. You should consider using VBscript, Jscript or Powershell to accomplish this task.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Squashman. I can learn Powershell and use in future projects. This script I'm doing here is ready to go. 99% done. The only problem is this inconsistency with <path> in Findstr command. So, forget we are dealing with XML. All I need is manipulate some lines using a script which is failing in some point. Can I get your help one more time?

Comment: Don't use double colons for comments inside a parenthesized code block.  It causes unforeseen problems.  Use the standard comment command which is `REM`.

Comment: You also overwrote a very important system variable.  Never use the word `PATH` as a variable name unless you know what you are doing.  Once you changed that system variable, it can longer find the location of the `FINDSTR` command.

Comment: Thank you @Squasman for all your help. Everything is working as I was expecting.